# Nesting functions in CoffeeScript argument without parentheses

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

The following code is working

```
app.router.navigate(abc.url.replace(/:\w+/g,
    (matched) -> someString)
, replace: true)
```

where the `navigate` method takes two arguments, one `function` that returns a string (the modified URL) and one `plain object` ({replace: true})

Now I would like to remove the parentheses for consistency, but the following code didn't work

```
app.router.navigate abc.url.replace /:\w+/g,
    (matched) -> someString
, replace: nextView.replace
```

How do I make it work with minimal parentheses?

Comment: Have you considered the fact that parentheses make your code more readable? Both of your examples are pretty difficult to read, but the one with parentheses is definitely more readable. Parentheses in CoffeeScript are usually optional, but that doesn't mean they're undesirable.

Comment: You're allowed (and even encouraged) to use variables and small functions to increase readability. Just because you can do something in one opaque mess of a statement doesn't mean you should.